# How do I count comparisons in my code? I need a variable counter and then I need to return it

Tags: python, counter

```py
import random

def QuickSort(Lista):
  if len(Lista) <= 1: return Lista
      
  min = []
  ugu = []
  mag = []
  pivot = Lista[-1]
    
  for i in Lista:
    if i < pivot: min.append(i)
    elif i == pivot: ugu.append(i)
    else: mag.append(i)
    
  return QuickSort(min) + ugu + QuickSort(mag)

l = [random.randrange(10) for i in range(10)]
print(QuickSort(l))
```

Comment: Please explain where you're stuck with this.  Any intro to a programming language will teach you how to initialize and increment a counter.  You merely have to place an increment to execute at every point that you do a comparison.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: apart from your title which is too detailed and your question that lacks any details, you're using 'min' as a variable. stack overflow doesn't let you post all-code questions for a reason, it's not appropriate to just format your code as text and post your question.

Comment: Sorry i barely use this site so i'm still learning how to use it, my problem is i know how to do a variable counter the problem is i don't understand where i need to put it. I have tried several times but i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You could do the comparison separately.

```
count = 0

def lt(a, b):
    global count
    count += 1
    if a < b:
        return True
    return False

def eq(a, b):
    global count
    count += 1
    if a == b:
        return True
    return False

def quicksort(tosort):
    if len(tosort) <= 1:
        return tosort
    minside = []
    middle = []
    maxside = []
    pivot = tosort[-1]
    for i in tosort:
        if lt(i, pivot):
            minside.append(i)
        elif eq(i, pivot):
            middle.append(i)
        else:
            maxside.append(i)
    return quicksort(minside) + middle + quicksort(maxside)

tosort = [
    [*range(10)],
    [*range(9, -1, -1)],
    [5, 2, 9, 2, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2, 4]
]
for sorting, name in [(quicksort, 'quicksort')]:
    for alist in tosort:
        sorting(alist.copy())
        count = 0
        print(
            f"{name} {alist} {sorting(alist.copy())} {count}"
        )
```

Comment: Does it work with multiple list? both sort and counter?

Comment: You have to put the count in the right place. You could also make it work with the built-in sorted by defining your own comparison. Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: basically for a school test i need to compare 2 type of sort, with 2 list and i need the counter of both list, with the first sort i had no problem instead the quick is giving me so much problems. So i need to pass two list as parameters from the global to the quick sort function.

Comment: Meh, realised I'd made an error and corrected to bring the code out. I also think its better to use static lists. You should be able to add another sort in pretty easily.